# Create Pmax Campaign Retail for selective products with Usage of REST API v12 or v14 OR Google Ads PHP Library using laravel

Tags: laravel, google-ads-api

I have been working with Google Ads API for creation of the campaign and other stuff.

Now i have criteria to create pmax retail campaign for selective products based on their Product Item ids.

Though creating the pmax campaign for shopping vertical is working well with inclusion of the all products but when it comes to creation with selective or specific products with the use of their ProductItemId i am getting errors.

At the first part i started creating **Campaign Budget** as it is needed to be assigned in **Campaign **Creation then followed by creating various assets or Listing Group Filters to bifurcate the data and other required  things like creating **AssetGroup** and **assetGroupListingGroupFilters**.

While creating the Pmax Campaign with All Product things works well.

I have series of the functions to fulfill their creation.

Campaign Budget - Endpoint used is => **campaignBudgets:mutate**
Campaign Creation - Endpoint used is => **campaigns:mutate**
And so on .

As while creation of the **assetGroupListingGroupFilters** nodes are meant be created where we need to define the criteria of the products based on which you need to create Pmax Campaign for Retail.

I am following the doc and tried with the same but getting error all the time when i used SUBDIVISION as the type of the **assetGroupListingGroupFilters** and the error is **SUBDIVISION_MUST_HAVE_EVERYTHING_ELSE_CHILD**.

I tried getting help from google Developer Forum but that keep pointing towards the docs where things are not clear enough.

Additionally as per the last revert i got they asked to use **googleAds:mutate** which allows to create the Temp Resources with use of the negative values like -1 where that can be bind or used within the linking of the assets or relative hierarchy but still no luck.

Any guidance or support would be helpful.

I am using **REST API v12** for the operation with **Laravel** or any example with Google Ads Library for PHP would also be good.

Just to clarify one more thing i tried running the example from the Google Ads Library itself named **AddPerformanceMaxRetailCampaign.php** but getting error of Maximun execution time.

Thanks in Advance

I have working model for the creation of the campaign with All products that is working fine and i tried with multiple ways to create the nodes but none them is effective